# Android (Xamarin) FCM Push Notification OnRefreshToken not called but Token invalidated

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

we have a crossplattform App (Xamarin). For push-notifications we are using Plugin.PushNotification 1.3.0 . 
On iOS everything seems to work absolutely fine. But on Android we sometimes have the problem, that our registration ID gets invalidated or at least it seems like that's the case.
When our server sends a message to FCM we get a response that the registration ID is not registered anymore. This only happens with some devices.  And expiration time makes no sense because in one case it happend after 3 days.

There was also no OnTokenRefresh Event. We always send the current ID to the server when the app is opened and of course if the OnTokenRefresh would be fired.

Does anyone have an idea or at least know the problem?
What would happen if the app is closed, while the id was invalidated, for whatever reason? 
Or could there be a relation to Android Oreo? We're trying to validate, but at the moment it seems that it only happens to recent devices.

We've narrowed the problem down a little. 
In Android the event is called but not in Xamarin Forms. So this works:

```
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                PushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "myEvents";
                PushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "myChannel";
            }

            PushNotificationManager.SoundUri = Uri.Parse($"{ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{AppContext.PackageName}/raw/alarm");

            // this seems to get called
            CrossPushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : {p.Token}");
            };


    #if DEBUG
            PushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
    #else
                  PushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);
    #endif
        }
```

And this OnTokenRefresh does not:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    public new static App Current;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;

        MainPage = new MainPage();
        var crossPushListener = CrossPushNotificationListener.Instance;
    }
}
```

CrossPushNotificationListener:

```
namespace MobileApp1
{
    public class CrossPushNotificationListener
    {
        private static CrossPushNotificationListener _instance;

        public static CrossPushNotificationListener Instance
        {
            get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new CrossPushNotificationListener()); }
            private set { _instance = value; }
        }

        public CrossPushNotificationListener()
        {
            CrossPushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += OnTokenRefreshNotify;
        }

        // this function is not executed. Does that make sense?
        private async void OnTokenRefreshNotify(object sender, PushNotificationTokenEventArgs args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : {args.Token}");
            Upload(args.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

As long as the app is running, both work. But if the app is closed only Android code is executed.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Hello, @Buschi Welcome to StackOverflow Please read the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide by stack to understand how to ask a better question. Please add some code to your question

Comment: @Buschi I recommend not use plug ins for important functionality. Read the Xamarin documentation how to implement push notifications for iOS and Android with platform specific code. It will be easier to debug, otherwise you rely on the creator of the plug-in to fix any problems or to update in case iOS and or Android change anything regarding how the push notifications work. Here is a good tutorial on push notifications, but I do not think it accounts for creating notification channels for Android starting with Oreo but you can look that up:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le2lDY22xwM&t=4s

Comment: @Buschi did you try to force the token refresh by deleting the current firebase instance in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

while the app was running everything worked fine, just not while it was not running.

It seems that the service can only execute Android code without XamarinForms.
We solved this by implementing

```
        CrossPushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
        {
            SendToken(p.Token);
        };
```

in Android without any XamarinForms (so also no dependencyServices).

Thanks for the feedback.